# Docker - UDP Broadcast not working under MacOS

Tags: macos, docker, udp

I have a python application which searches for a device on the network through UDP broadcast packets. My code works well under Windows, MacOS (Darwin), Docker (Windows Host), but not Docker on MacOS (Darwin). Can someone point me in a direction to find and solve the cause.

The Mac IP (and device to be found) has an IP of 192.168.2.x
Normally 192.168.2.255 as a broadcast works

Python Code:
(with various Broadcast addresses tried for MacOS)

```
server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM, socket.IPPROTO_UDP)
server.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_BROADCAST, 1)
server.settimeout(0.2)
server.bind(("", 9302))
message = msgpack.packb({“service”: “control.ws”})
a=2
print("\tLooking for Server:")
while a>1:
    print("\t\tSending broadcast #"+str(a))
    server.sendto(message, (Broadcast_Addr, 9101))
    print("\t\t…Broadcast to: “, Broadcast_Addr)
    time.sleep(1)
    try:
        data, addr = server.recvfrom(1024)
    except socket.error as e:
        print(“Error getting socket data: %s” % e)
        print(“Exiting Program Now”)
        sys.exit(1)
    except:
        print(”****Stopped looking - Major Error!")
        sys.exit(1)
    else:
        Server_Data = msgpack.unpackb(data)
        #Server was found
a=a-1
```

Windows Docker call (which works)

```
docker run -it -p 8765:8765 -v C:\ABC_Volume:/logs -p 9101:9101/udp -p 9302:9302/udp myimage:v1
```

MacOS Docker call (does not work)*

```
m$ docker run -it -p 8765:8765 -p 9101:9101/udp -p 9302:9302/udp  myimage.v1
```

[Docker Information from MacOS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gj0VW.png)

Comment: In what way doesn't it work?  Can you correct the indentation and quotes in your Python code?  The `docker run` lines you have launch shells instead of running your script, and have some `--link` to other containers; can you provide a [mcve] that's sufficient to build and run this?

Comment: It doesn't work in that the python code never finds the device on the network. I'm not sure if the broadcast doesn't make it off the host, or the reply doesn't come back (I don't know how to check this).

Sorry about the code and commands - I have cleaned them up. I am not sure how you could reproduce as you need the device to be found.

Answer (score 0):

UDP broadcasts and host networking does not work on Docker for Mac.  Your code is likely fine (since it works on all of the other platforms).  Best solution would be to spin up a VM and run docker from within there.